# Direct messages with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chat

I've stumbled on a theoretical problem when trying to create a realtime chat with socket.io and node.js.

**The problem**

After a socket connection has been authenticated I am storing the socket in a list, so that I can keep track of authenticated sockets and which user they belong to.

When a user sends a message to another user, the message is first stored in the database. After the message has been stored the server loops through the list of authenticated sockets to see if the reciever is online. If the receiver is online, the message is sent instantly, if the receiver is not online he/she will find his/hers message history in the database when first loading the page.

With the above solution, what would happen if there were a large amount of users online at the same time? In realtime chats the users often send a lot of messages in a short period of time, and if the server must loop through all users that are online everytime one user sends a message, then the server would have some serious troubles keeping up, right?

My initial thought was to store the socket's session id in the database, because MongoDB doesn't need O(n) amount of time to find database entries. This isn't really possible in my case though, because my site will have many different views, and each time the user changes view, a new socket will be created. And if a new socket id is stored in the db very often, there could occur problems due to the asynchronous event-based nature of node.js, right?

**My solution**

My only idea to solve this problem is to create a "large enough" empty array:

```
var sockets = new Array(100*1000);
```

When a new user is created it is then given an id, based on the number of currently existing users (user no. 54 would be given id 54 etc.).

When a new socket is created, it will be stored in the *sockets* array on the position defined by the authorised user's id (as stored in the db).

So when person *A* with database id 54 sends a direct message to person *B* with database id 125 the server will know that *if person B is currently online, her/his socket will be in the sockets array at position 125*, and vice versa.

Pros:

- Direct indexing in an array (sockets[125]) is much faster than looping through all sockets.
- Page loads will have complexity O(1 + k) where k is whatever complexity socket.io require to establish a socket connection.
- When a user gets a new socket, it is thread safe to swap out the old one, since no asynchronous functions are required to change the socket in the *sockets* array (unlike mongodb which requires calling asynchronous functions).

Cons:

- A "large enough" empty array could be a lot of wasted memory.
- If the number of users should ever exceed the "large enough" limit, the application must be changed in order to make it work again.

**My question**

Are there any problems to my solution that I haven't considered? Are there any existing solutions to this question that are better than mine?

**Edit**

Some additional questions:

- Is direct access from an array made in O(1) amount of time in javascript?
- Approximately how much memory would an array with 100 000 empty objects require?

Comment: are you using ```socket.io-redis```?

Comment: No, never heard of it. Will check it out!

Comment: why the extra mapping of session -> array index? why not use an object? and add / cleanup keys as necessary? object key access should be constant.  With a vanilla object you shouldn't have to worry about preallocation, jsut let node/js handle it ?

Comment: Why not maintain an additional lookup table from username to socket to check if a user has an (authenticated) socket assigned to them?

Comment: @dm03514 never considered that, always assumed that objects are made for "small" sets of data. Do you think an object could manage thousands of entries and still maintain constant access time?